# ¿Donde debe ir mi return?

Tags: javascript, bucles, while

debo hacer una funcion que aumente el valor en 5 del valor recibido hasta un limite de 8 veces y luego retornar el valor final. Esto lo debo hacer usando el bucle do while. Escribi mi codigo pero no me devuelve el valor final sino el primer valor obtenido luego de la suma es decir, si el valor que paso por parametro es 5 me devuelve 10 en vez del valor final. Les dejo mi codigo, me ayudarian bastante diciendome cual es el error que tengo

```
function doWhile(numero) {
  let contador = 0
  let num = numero
  do {
    num = numero + 5
    contador ++
  } while (contador < 9) 
  return num 
}
```

Comment: Siempre estás haciendo la misma operación: `num = numero + 5`, asignando el valor recibido por parámetro + 5. Para incrementar debería ser `num = num + 5` o, simplificando, `num += 5`

Comment: es verdad, muchas gracias

Comment: No es necesario introducir otra variable. Puedes modificar directamente el parámetro. Por ejemplo: `numero += 5`. Entonces la variable `num` está demás.

Answer (score 2):

Según los criterios definidos "una función que aumente el valor en 5 del valor recibido has un límite de 8 veces.", deberías recorrer el contador hasta 8 si empiezas en 0.

```
function doWhile(numero) {
  let contador = 0;
  do {
    numero += 5
    contador ++
  } while (contador < 8) 
  return numero 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu lógica esta muy bien pero creo que te equivocaste al poner la variable "numero" en el aumento dentro del do while, debido que esta variable solo la utilizas para poder setear el valor a tu variable num.
Así deberia quedar:

```
function doWhile(numero) {
  let contador = 0;
  let num = numero;
  do {
    num += 5
    contador ++
  } while (contador < 9) 
  return num 
}
```

O para que no te confundas al mismo dato que entra como parametro en tu función (numero) úsala para el incremento:

```
function doWhile(numero) {
  let contador = 0;
  do {
    numero += 5
    contador ++
  } while (contador < 9) 
  return numero 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que me percaté es que tu variable `num` (que estás retornando) nunca incrementa, por ello siempre retornará el primer valor que se almacene:

```js
function doWhile(numero) {
  let contador = 0;
  let num = numero;
  do {
    num = numero + 5; // <-- aquí está el error.
    contador++;
  } while (contador < 9) 
  return num;
}

console.log(doWhile(8));
```

La solución sería que a esa variable le incrementes 5 con el operador aritmético `+=`, con esto la variable irá incrementando mediante repita el ciclo del `do while`:

```js
function doWhile(numero) {
  let contador = 0;
  let num = numero;
  do {
    num += 5; // <-- la variable incrementará
    contador++;
  } while (contador < 9) 
  return num; // <-- retornamos el resultado de la variable
}

console.log(doWhile(8));
```